# How to Install or enable PHP-FTP support on Linux Apache server?

Tags: rhel, php, ftp

In my PHP code I am using the below function

```
ftp_connect()
```

But it throws an error, FTP is not enabled for PHP.

Can any one tell me how to enable/install FTP in RHEL, `Apache2.2` server,PHP Version is 5.3.3.

This server is **Production** now my concern is if I reinstall PHP is it going to disturb my current environment?

Answer (score 1):

`php.ini` has a directive has been named `disable_functions` , For example:

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
```

Your system administrator may have banned your `ftp_connect()` with the directive above.